# X11 window server connection keeps expiring

Tags: ssh, x11

I am ssh'ing into a network using the -X flag so the GUI appears on my host rather than the remote host.

But after testing my program a few times, I get that the X11 window server connection is dead. It just tells me it can't connect as if I didn't ssh in with the -X flag.

What can I do to fix this other than keep logging in and out? This is a networking assignment so I am logging onto multiple remote hosts and having them communicate with each other.

The exact error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. 
     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method) 
     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:178) 
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142) 
     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) 
     at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironm    ent.java:82) 
     at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495) 
     at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548) 
     at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419) 
     at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384) 
     at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174) 
     at Client.<init>(Client.java:37) 
     at Client.main(Client.java:570)
```

Comment: Seems like your SSH connection itself is dropped. Did you enable keepalive in your config file (ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax)? Or perhaps disabled TCPKeepAlive?

Comment: I mean I am still have connection to the remote host and can execute files so I don't think the connection is dropped.

Comment: How is your DISPLAY environment variable being set to 'localhost:10.0'? Are you setting it, or is ssh setting it for you?

Comment: Are other people logging into the same account from other machines? They could overwrite the .Xauthority file in the home directory. Check if the file disappears or changes timestamp.